# Why do some turbofan-engined Caravelles, but not all, have an anti-shock body at the root of the horizontal stabilizers?

Tags: aircraft-design, horizontal-stabilizer, vertical-stabilizer, sud-caravelle

Many turbofan-engined Caravelles have a prominent [anti-shock body](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anti-shock_body) where the horizontal stabilizers attach to the vertical tail, about a quarter of the way up the latter.  (*Turbojet*-engined Caravelles don't have it.)

For instance:

[image: Caravelle with a carrot up its rear]

(Image by Aldo Bidini at [Airliners.net](https://www.airliners.net/photo/Air-City/Sud-SE-210-Caravelle/1190642/L), via Russavia at [Wikimedia Commons](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Air_City_Caravelle_Bidini.jpg).)

*This* Caravelle 10B, however, does not:

[image: Caravelle sans carrot]

(Image by Rob Schleiffert at [Flickr](https://www.flickr.com/photos/109661044@N07/28953091041/), via Helmy oved at [Wikimedia Commons](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Se210_French_Air_Force_(28953091041).jpg).)

Why do some turbofan-engined Caravelles have an anti-shock body in this location, while some other instances of the very same Caravelle variants lack one?

Comment: It looks like an application of area rule to compensate for the fan's lager nacelles, which were likely increasing the build up of the transonic shock wave behind the engines.

Comment: @JohnK: Then why didn't _all_ turbofan-engined Caravelles have this anti-shock body?

Comment: Not sure, but the non-fan engine in the lower pic is quite a bit forward from the one in the top pic.  Maybe other turbofans also have the forward engine placement?

Comment: @JohnK: Both of the pictures in the question are of turbofan-engined Caravelle 10Bs.  The difference in apparent engine position is an artifact of perspective resulting from the differing angles at which the two aircraft were photographed.